# how to insert in oracle 10g database and returns the ID generated using stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am very new to oracle's sql developer (since we've studied mysql) as well as in programming. I've searched in this website the answer to my question but I really can't understand the solutions provided.

What I want is to return the ID generated after inserting an object from java into the database. I'm using mybatis and oracle 10g database. I've already created the table and its columns.

Here's my code for the mapper

`<insert id="addUser" parameterType="User" statementType="CALLABLE">
    { CALL addUserSP(
        #{user.surname, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
        #{user.firstName, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=IN},
        #{userId, javaType=Integer, jdbcType=NUMBER, mode=OUT}
     )}
</insert>`

Here's my stored procedure (and I've already create a package named 'CREATEUSER')

```
PROCEDURE ADDUSERSP
( surname IN VARCHAR2, 
  firstName IN VARCHAR2,
  userId OUT NUMBER
) AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO users("surname", "first_name")
VALUES (surname, firstName);
RETURNING user_id INTO userId;

END ADDUSERSP;
```

According to what I've found here, it seems that I need to create a trigger(?) and sequence(?) to make the user_id auto increment whenever I add new data into the table. However, I have no idea how to do it.

Here are my questions:
Is my stored procedure right? Are the codes incomplete? I mean, I have not declared the package in the mapper and I've seen that it is needed (?), something like this `{ CALL [CreateUser].[addUserSP]( blah blah...`. Should I write a sequence and trigger or there is an easy way to make the primary key `user_id` to be auto incremented? Kindly also check the syntax. I have a lot of problems in syntax.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT in Oracle, that pattern (as you found) does use a SEQUENCE object and a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

As a demonstration, something like this for the sequence object:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

And something like this for the before insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.id IS NULL THEN
      SELECT myseq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id FROM DUAL;
   END IF;
END
```

---

As far as the procedure, I'm not a big fan of extra PL/SQL blocks that wrap a SQL INSERT statement.

It looks like you have an extra semicolon, before RETURNING. That clause is part of the INSERT statement, not a separate statement.

One big gotcha to be aware of is that SQL statements within a PL/SQL block can reference both columns and PL/SQL variables. When variables have the same names as columns, you will likely encounter behavior you didn't expect.

Typically PL/SQL author use a naming convention for variables that reduces the likelihood of name collisions. We frequently see variables with names like `v_surname`. (Personally, I use a slightly different convention, but the variable names "look like" variable names, not column references. And I don't name columns following the pattern I use for variables.)

The double quotes around the identifiers are acceptable, but this does make the identifiers case sensitive. When identifiers aren't enclosed in double quotes, Oracle treats them as if they were UPPER CASE.  Just make sure that your table was defined with lower case column names.

Comment: noted! thank you so much spencer! i'll try to do what you have told

Comment: should i write the code you have provided in the same script as the procedure? or in the folders of sequences and triggers? sorry i'm not really familiar with these stuff! :(

Comment: The SEQUENCE and TRIGGER are separate database objects. That particular trigger is associated with the "users" table. As far as which "folder" those should be kept in...  Once those objects are created in the database, the schema browser of your client is going to show them wherever. In terms of the .sql files, that TRIGGER is associated with the table, so I'd 'd keep it close to the table definition, even in the same script with the table. If I use a separate SEQUENCE object for each table, then I'd keep the .sql for that SEQUENCE close to the definition of the table and trigger.